# Change blueprint number of columns?

Tags: grid, sass, compass-sass, blueprint-css

I'm using Compass for the first time.
Instead of having 24 columns and 10px gutters, I'd like to have 12 columns and 20px gutters.
If I put "width:960px" on my #container, the .showgrid class shows me a correct grid based on this :

```
$blueprint-grid-columns: 12;
$blueprint-container-size: 950px;
$blueprint-grid-margin: 20px;
```

I've put this in my _base.scss, and here is the result :

[image: showgrid]
There are 12 columns for a total width of 960px. Right.

But if I apply "width:span(12)" or "include column(12)" on my container, it shows me only 6 columns for a total width of 480px (960/2) :

[image: showgrid]
The widths are wrong and based on the original sizes : 24 columns.

Do you know why and how I could fix that?

And, subsidiary question : do you know how to remove the lines relative to line-height on .showgrid ?

Comment: I tried it and it worked for me as expected. Could you please share your code via http://sassbin.com so that we can fiddle with it?

Comment: Hi! I don't have my code anymore, I've moved on Susy, which seems to be more flexible and more powerful regarding my expectations. Thanks for your reply :)

Comment: The most modern and flexible grid system is [Singulary](https://github.com/Team-Sass/Singularity). Susy authors are also developing a modern version, called Susy Next, but there hasn't been any news for months.